# Check in range of multiple float variables

Tags: python

User input scores of subjects and I need to check if these scores are valid (0->10, step is 0.1 because for exp: 5.25 or 5.1 is acceptable). Below is my code:

```
def Task_22():
    mathematics = float(input("Input mathematics score: "))
    literature  = float(input("Input literature score: "))
    english     = float(input("Input english score: "))
    # check valid score
    if all(i in range(0,11) for i in [mathematics, literature, english]):
        print("OK")
    else: print("NOK")
```

but when input as below, the result is not as my expected:

```
Input mathematics score: 2
Input literature score: 5
Input english score: 7.25
NOK
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `range()` function lets you create an iterator so you can loop over some integers. When you use `i in range(0, 11)`, you're essentially asking "will `range(0, 11)` eventually iterate over `i`", **not** "is `i` within the upper and lower bounds of `range(0, 11)`". Because `range()` only works with integers, a float will be iterator over by `range`, and thus a float will never be `in` a range.

What you really want to do is check if the number is greater or equal to a lower bound and less than or equal to an upper bound, using operators like `>=` and `<=`.

```
def Task_22():
    mathematics = float(input("Input mathematics score: "))
    literature  = float(input("Input literature score: "))
    english     = float(input("Input english score: "))
    # check valid score
    if all(0 <= i <= 10 for i in [mathematics, literature, english]):
        print("OK")
    else: print("NOK")
```

Comment: I think that the OP is wanting `0 <= i <= 10`